# why doesn't my if check work, characther comparisasion

Tags: python, if-statement

```
a = input("input a name ")
print("your name is: ",a)
print(a[-1])
if a[-1] == "e" or "a":
    print(a, "there is either a e or a in the name")
    print(a[-1])
elif a[-1] == "s":
    print(a,"there is s ")
else:
    print(a,"there isnt e or a in the name")
```

Dont understand what I am doing wrong, no matter what u input it will always get stuck on the first if statement

Comment: @deceze `a[-1] == "e" or "a"` this will be evaluated as `a[-1] == 'e' and 'e' or 'a'` according to operator chaining right?

Comment: @Ch3steR It will be evaluated as "does the last character equal 'e' or is 'a' a truthy value". Not much to do with operator chaining.

Answer (score 1):

```
if a[-1] == "e" or "a"
```

always evaluates to True because `"a"` is truthy and you are not testing the equality of `a[-1]` with `"a"`, simply the value `"a"` itself. Instead, you mean to write:

```
if a[-1] == "e" or a[-1] == "a"
```

An alternative, preferable solution could be:

```
if a[-1] in ["e", "a"]
```

which tests whether the last character is in the list `["e", "a"]`.